# Hibernate не создает таблицы

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

Hibernate не создает таблицы в MySql.

spring-hibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactoryBean"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="packagesToScan">
    <list>
        <value>az.inventar.model</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

spring-database.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventardb" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="123456" />
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
</bean>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="az.inventar.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<import resource="spring-database.xml" />
<import resource="spring-hibernate.xml" />

<bean
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

несколько сущностей

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "branch")
public class Branch {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee employee;

public Branch() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Branch(int id, String name, Employee employee) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.employee = employee;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employee = employee;
}
```

и

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Users user;
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "branch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Branch branch;
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "equip", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Equip> equip;

public Employee() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public Employee(int id, String name, String surname, Users user, Branch branch, List<Equip> equip) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.user = user;
    this.branch = branch;
    this.equip = equip;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Users getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Users user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Branch getBranch() {
    return branch;
}

public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
    this.branch = branch;
}

public List<Equip> getEquip() {
    return equip;
}

public void setEquip(List<Equip> equip) {
    this.equip = equip;
}
```

Hibernate логи:

> 10:54:58,515 INFO DispatcherServlet:489 - FrameworkServlet
>   'dispatcher': initialization started 10:54:58,546 INFO
>   XmlWebApplicationContext:578 - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for
>   namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Apr 04 10:54:58 AZST
>   2016]; root of context hierarchy 10:54:58,612 INFO
>   XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml] 10:54:59,203
>   INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml] 10:54:59,241
>   INFO XmlBeanDefinitionReader:317 - Loading XML bean definitions from
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml] 10:54:59,952
>   INFO RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:532 - Looking for @ControllerAdvice:
>   WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date
>   [Mon Apr 04 10:54:58 AZST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   10:55:00,079 INFO RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:532 - Looking for
>   @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace
>   'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon Apr 04 10:54:58 AZST 2016];
>   root of context hierarchy 10:55:00,245 INFO
>   DriverManagerDataSource:133 - Loaded JDBC driver:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 10:55:00,679 DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 -
>   Adding type registration boolean ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@3f224eff 10:55:00,680 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration boolean ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@3f224eff 10:55:00,680 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@3f224eff 10:55:00,684 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration numeric_boolean ->
>   org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType@6d6a72f2 10:55:00,694 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration true_false ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType@7250b542 10:55:00,698 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration yes_no ->
>   org.hibernate.type.YesNoType@19fb9663 10:55:00,706 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration byte ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ByteType@4cbbf7f4 10:55:00,707 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration byte ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ByteType@4cbbf7f4 10:55:00,708 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Byte ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ByteType@4cbbf7f4 10:55:00,712 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration character ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@19fb7a3c 10:55:00,712 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration char ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@19fb7a3c 10:55:00,713 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Character
>   -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@19fb7a3c 10:55:00,724 DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration short ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ShortType@3efdd686 10:55:00,724 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration short ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ShortType@3efdd686 10:55:00,725 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Short ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ShortType@3efdd686 10:55:00,727 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration integer ->
>   org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@6b38579e 10:55:00,727 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration int ->
>   org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@6b38579e 10:55:00,727 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Integer ->
>   org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@6b38579e 10:55:00,732 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration long ->
>   org.hibernate.type.LongType@726c21e5 10:55:00,732 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration long ->
>   org.hibernate.type.LongType@726c21e5 10:55:00,733 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Long ->
>   org.hibernate.type.LongType@726c21e5 10:55:00,738 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration float ->
>   org.hibernate.type.FloatType@4ab9bc66 10:55:00,738 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration float ->
>   org.hibernate.type.FloatType@4ab9bc66 10:55:00,739 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Float ->
>   org.hibernate.type.FloatType@4ab9bc66 10:55:00,746 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration double ->
>   org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@28031121 10:55:00,747 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration double ->
>   org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@28031121 10:55:00,747 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Double ->
>   org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@28031121 10:55:00,759 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration big_decimal ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType@2ab937ac 10:55:00,759 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.math.BigDecimal
>   -> org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType@2ab937ac 10:55:00,764 DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration big_integer ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BigIntegerType@2b1390c9 10:55:00,765 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.math.BigInteger
>   -> org.hibernate.type.BigIntegerType@2b1390c9 10:55:00,769 DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration string ->
>   org.hibernate.type.StringType@6ec5f31e 10:55:00,770 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.String ->
>   org.hibernate.type.StringType@6ec5f31e 10:55:00,772 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration nstring ->
>   org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType@194b899d 10:55:00,778 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration ncharacter ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterNCharType@5177bcb 10:55:00,780 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration url ->
>   org.hibernate.type.UrlType@28dbcc4d 10:55:00,781 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.net.URL ->
>   org.hibernate.type.UrlType@28dbcc4d 10:55:00,788 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration date ->
>   org.hibernate.type.DateType@a33c98c 10:55:00,789 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.sql.Date ->
>   org.hibernate.type.DateType@a33c98c 10:55:00,796 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration time ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimeType@49cda1d4 10:55:00,796 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.sql.Time ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimeType@49cda1d4 10:55:00,804 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration timestamp ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@4b8fa058 10:55:00,804 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.sql.Timestamp ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@4b8fa058 10:55:00,805 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.util.Date ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@4b8fa058 10:55:00,807 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration dbtimestamp ->
>   org.hibernate.type.DbTimestampType@756b5ac7 10:55:00,816 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration calendar ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@64b24f1 10:55:00,817 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.util.Calendar ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@64b24f1 10:55:00,817 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@64b24f1
>   10:55:00,825 DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration
>   calendar_date -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarDateType@49574f22
>   10:55:00,828 DEBUG BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration
>   locale -> org.hibernate.type.LocaleType@6ebe10dd 10:55:00,829 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.util.Locale ->
>   org.hibernate.type.LocaleType@6ebe10dd 10:55:00,831 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration currency ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@386fd9f1 10:55:00,831 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.util.Currency ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@386fd9f1 10:55:00,834 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration timezone ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimeZoneType@4bb217b8 10:55:00,834 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.util.TimeZone ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TimeZoneType@4bb217b8 10:55:00,836 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration class ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ClassType@fedb05d 10:55:00,836 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Class ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ClassType@fedb05d 10:55:00,843 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration uuid-binary ->
>   org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@31eedb3f 10:55:00,843 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.util.UUID ->
>   org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@31eedb3f 10:55:00,844 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration uuid-char ->
>   org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType@63ba4c7c 10:55:00,846 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration pg-uuid ->
>   org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@172d56f6 10:55:00,850 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration binary ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@834f782 10:55:00,851 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration byte[] ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@834f782 10:55:00,851 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration [B ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@834f782 10:55:00,854 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration wrapper-binary ->
>   org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@3785babe 10:55:00,854 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration Byte[] ->
>   org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@3785babe 10:55:00,855 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration [Ljava.lang.Byte; ->
>   org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@3785babe 10:55:00,857 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration image ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ImageType@71c19bf7 10:55:00,865 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration characters ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharArrayType@7b4ff56a 10:55:00,865 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration char[] ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharArrayType@7b4ff56a 10:55:00,865 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration [C ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharArrayType@7b4ff56a 10:55:00,867 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration wrapper-characters ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayType@277c2b4e 10:55:00,867 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration
>   [Ljava.lang.Character; ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayType@277c2b4e 10:55:00,868 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration Character[] ->
>   org.hibernate.type.CharacterArrayType@277c2b4e 10:55:00,872 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration text ->
>   org.hibernate.type.TextType@75e64723 10:55:00,873 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration ntext ->
>   org.hibernate.type.NTextType@54ff1aab 10:55:00,890 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration blob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BlobType@7e1fa11d 10:55:00,891 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.sql.Blob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.BlobType@7e1fa11d 10:55:00,892 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration materialized_blob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType@75fa563e 10:55:00,904 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration clob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ClobType@2a8392b5 10:55:00,904 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.sql.Clob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ClobType@2a8392b5 10:55:00,913 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration nclob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.NClobType@772f11c2 10:55:00,914 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.sql.NClob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.NClobType@772f11c2 10:55:00,914 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration materialized_clob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType@5939fed6 10:55:00,915 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration materialized_nclob ->
>   org.hibernate.type.MaterializedNClobType@131dda2d 10:55:00,918 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration serializable ->
>   org.hibernate.type.SerializableType@28c61629 10:55:00,927 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration object ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ObjectType@6f14d1b5 10:55:00,927 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration java.lang.Object ->
>   org.hibernate.type.ObjectType@6f14d1b5 10:55:00,928 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_date ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@1f5198d0 10:55:00,929 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_time ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@26078fc0 10:55:00,929 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_timestamp ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@3a6e99c1 10:55:00,929 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_dbtimestamp ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@33306bdf 10:55:00,930 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_calendar ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@2ffa17ba 10:55:00,930 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_calendar_date ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@4c2bccf1 10:55:00,930 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_binary ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@4f9c0948 10:55:00,930 DEBUG
>   BasicTypeRegistry:146 - Adding type registration imm_serializable ->
>   org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@d257ecd 10:55:01,001 INFO
>   Version:66 - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
>   10:55:01,032 INFO Version:54 - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.8.Final}
>   10:55:01,043 INFO Environment:239 - HHH000206: hibernate.properties
>   not found 10:55:01,047 INFO Environment:346 - HHH000021: Bytecode
>   provider name : javassist 10:55:01,983 INFO Dialect:145 - HHH000400:
>   Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect 10:55:02,447 WARN
>   XmlWebApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'sessionFactoryBean' while setting bean property
>   'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No
>   identifier specified for entity: az.inventar.model.UserRoles
>   10:55:02,480 ERROR DispatcherServlet:502 - Context initialization
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'sessionFactoryBean' while setting bean property
>   'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No
>   identifier specified for entity: az.inventar.model.UserRoles at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>   at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4914)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5201)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No
>   identifier specified for entity: az.inventar.model.UserRoles at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
>   ... 31 more Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No
>   identifier specified for entity: az.inventar.model.UserRoles at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:277)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:224)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:372)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:454)
>   at
>   org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:439)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
>   ... 38 more

Зачем в базе не создаются таблицы?

Проблема решилась изменением привязок. Поля не создавались изза аннотаций @OneToMany и другими.

Comment: Проблема решилась. Проблема была в сущностях.

Answer (score 2):

Все в логах же.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: az.inventar.model.UserRoles at

У вас есть класс `UserRoles`, помеченный аннотацией `@Entity`, но без поля, выполняющего роль первичного ключа, с аннотацией `@Id`.

Comment: Добавил '@Id' но ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 0):

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">true</prop>
```

или

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

Кроме этого у вас не все поля помечены аннотациями. Такие как `username` и несколько других. 
Добавьте: `@JoinColumn(name="")`
А в одной ентити два `primary key`. 
Нужно полностью переписать связи.

Comment: Нужно ли ставить аннотации ко всем полям? Некоторые меня устраивают по умолчанию. И насчет привязок, я пробовал и без аннотаций (привязок), но таблицы все равно не создавались.

Comment: @Farik013 вам сначала нужно разобраться с тем, как работает гибернейт)

Comment: Я удалил все сущности и создал одну, без аннотаций. Все заработало, все же проблема была в привязках. Но и без аннотаций работает ))

Comment: оно работает без аннотации только  в том случае, когда имя поля одинаково с именем колонки в таблице.

Comment: у меня нет поля и колонки. я хочу создать и не меняя ничего, чтоб он создал таблицы с одинаковыми именами.